# How can I represent comma as superscript or subscript in python for the ax.text option of matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, label, ascii, subscript, superscript

How can represent a comma as superscript or subscript in the ax.text option of matplotlib?
For example I want to represent <sup>2,0</sup>B or B<sub>2,0</sub> for example.

Thanks in advance,
Lazaro

I tried '\u00B2\u2E34\u2070' for the superscript option but it gave me a weird character with the shape of an square.

Answer (score 0):

You can use math TeX text mode builtin in Matplotlib:

```
r'$^{2,0}$B or B$_{2,0}$'
```

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html